# Creating an online account & ordering system

Tags: plugins, paypal, account

Is it possible to create an account & ordering system with online payment (via paypal) for WP? Are there any kind of plugins for this?

We'd require some basket functionality so products can be added, an account area that could include order history and online payment to pay via paypal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most of the new and updated Cart/E-commerce plugins offer that functionality for ex:

- [**TheCartPress, E-Commerce for WordPress Stores**](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/thecartpress/) (long name for a plugin)
- [**wpStoreCart**](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wpstorecart/)
- [**DukaPress**](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/dukapress/)

Comment: Cheers, any idea's which is the easiest to implement and use?

Comment: Either DukaPress or TheCartPress should be fine

Comment: @Bainternet I'm back onto this project now. I'm struggling with them, they're very hard to adjust. Cartpress has pretty poor documentation and Dukapress seems even harder to adjust. I'm trying to put the most popular products on the homepage using Cartpress. Also where are the templates to adjust how all the different pages are laid out?

Comment: @Bainternet I'm using the default template in WP and want to get everything displayed on that.